# c#: Checking if datarow exists in a different datatable with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, loops, datatable, datarow

I want to check if a DataRow from one DataTable exists in a different DataTable.

I have two DataTables. There's going to be some DataRows that are the same and exist in both. **This would be so easy if I knew what columns would be there everytime, but I don't.** Using something along the lines of...

```
datatable.Rows[i].Field <String> columnName);
```

will not work since this field could be an integer, string, or a date/time. I do however know that the two files with share identical column names.

My code is in bits and pieces, but this is what it looks like so far. Right now I generate a list of column names, but that's about it.

```
for (var h = 0; h < origDbfFile.datatable.Columns.Count; h++) {

     columnNames.Add(origDbfFile.datatable.Columns[h].ColumnName);

}
```

I have a loop nightmare going on, if someone can find a cleaner solution, it'd be much appreciated!

```
for (int g = 0; g < origDbfFile.dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; g++)
{

     for (int h = 0; i < modDbfFile.dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Count; h++)
     {
           foreach (String columnName in columnNames)
           {
           String rowValue = origDbfFile.dataset.Tables[0].Rows[g].Field<String>(Convert.ToString(columnName));
           //test data
           result += "Column name: &nbsp: " + columnName + "<br/>";
           result += "Value &nbsp; " + rowValue + "<br/><br/>";
           //if logic will go below

            }

      }

 }
```

Comment: Your nested loop (h) is declaring `h` but checking against `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to grab the value not as an integer, string or date/time... but as a generic object. Then from there I can convert it to a string, then compare as if it were a string.

```
//check each column name for a change
foreach (String columnName in columnNames)
{
    //this grabs whatever value is in that field                            
    String origRowValue = "" + origRow.Field<Object>(columnName);
    String modRowValue = "" + modRow.Field<Object>(columnName);

    //check if they are the same
    if (origRowValue.Equals(modRowValue))
    {
        //if they aren the same, increase the number matched by one
        numberMatched++;
        //add the column to the list of columns that don't match

    }
    else
    {
        mismatchedColumns.Add(columnName);
    }

}
```

Clever solution or what? Thanks for all the help everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no issues with boxing/unboxing and value/reference types of row values, your code is pretty much all you can do with the given situation.

Of course you can make it fancier with linq and extension methods if you are into them

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static int IndexIn(this DataRow thisRow, DataTable table)
    {
        return table.Rows
            .OfType<DataRow>()
            .Select((row, i) => new { row, index = i + 1 })
            .Where(pair => EqCondition(thisRow, pair.row))
            .Select(pair => pair.index)
            .FirstOrDefault() - 1;
    }

    public static bool EqCondition(DataRow row1, DataRow row2)
    {
        // check for the equality of row values
        return true;
    }
}

...

for (int i = 0; i < tab1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var index = tab1.Rows[i].IndexIn(tab2);

    if (index < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The row at index {0} was not found in second table", i);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The row at index {0} was found in second table at index", i, index);
    }
}
```

but besides breaking after first match found, the code is quite the same.

My recomandation is to use ids equality though, keeping in mind that most of times data comes from a data sources with indexes and you may find yourself in this case.

PS. in your second **for** you have 2 errors

- you declared h but use i
- I suppose you should have used .**Rows**.Count

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a whirl tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 3.5 or later something like this will get you a list of column names that exist in both tables.

```
var columns = origDbfFile.datatable.Columns
    .Select(o => o.ColumnName)
    .Intersect(modDbfFile.datatable.Columns
               .Select(m => m.ColumnName));
```

Though I'm not sure this solves your overall problem. Can you please clarify a little more?

Comment: Grabbing the column names is no problem. 

The problem is when I'm doing my checks on each field (let's say for example, id, emp_start_date, etc) I can't dynamically tell what kind of field it is. (int, string, double, date, etc)

I'm looking at this class right now as a possible solution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer.aspx

I don't have the code in front of me right now.